# SharePoint method in workflow to get Lastname, Firstname from Firstname Lastname

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have a list column with a value of FIRSTNAME space LASTNAME and I need to know how to in workflow to convert that to Lastname, Firstname

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you can use a calculated column with the following formula

```
=PROPER(lastname)&" "&PROPER(firstname)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to display the Last name, First name in your workflow. 
You can use the following formula:

```
substring-after([listnamecolumn]," "), substring-before([listnamecolumn]," ")
```